# how schedule a job in airflow for first 4 business day (not on weekends) of the month

Tags: cron, airflow

job should run on first 4 business day(not on weekends) at 3 am
ex : 00 03 1-6 * 1-5 ==> jobs are running every day-of-week from Monday through Friday

1 - fri      03:00

4 - mon      03:00

5 - tue      03:00

6-  wed      03:00

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with a single cron expression. You could configure "the first Monday-Friday of the month" using the `#` symbol:

```
0 3 * * MON#1,TUE#1,WED#1,THU#1,FRI#1
```

However, sometimes Friday is part of the 4 business days (e.g. Wednesday 1 Thursday 2 Friday 3 <s>Saturday 4 Sunday 5</s> Monday 6 <s>Tuesday 7</s>), so you cannot simply exclude that.

Within Airflow, you currently have 2 options to work around this:

1. Implement a [timetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/timetable.html)
2. Run your DAG with the expression shown above, and start your DAG with a task to skip all remaining tasks in case the DAG run's date is a fifth working day.